# What are the penalties for dying in The Division?

Tags: the-division

I'm curious what penalties, if any, there are for dying. I can think of three cases that might be different, though maybe there are more.

- Dying in PVE
- Dying as a non-rogue in the Dark Zone.
- Dying as a rogue in the Dark Zone.

I already know dying as a rogue gets some sort of penalty, but I'm looking for exact numbers.

Answer (score 12):

**PVE:** Nearly nothing. You will restart in a safe house. If on a Story Mission, you will restart at the last checkpoint. The npcs are also reset so you have to face the same opponents again.

**Non Rogue:** You will lose all unsaved Dark Zone loot items, some Dark Zone credits (~1700), a few rank Points (~1500-2000) and keys (normally i use just a single key, even if i carry ~40).
Killing 10-15 mobs will get you to the same DZ credit/rank level again.

**Rogue:** Same as non-rogue, but a higher amount of rank and dark zone credits.
After Patch 1.02: The lost amount of rank and DZ credits was dramatically decreased, it doesnt hurt too much, even if on manhunt now.

If you are rogue, your rogue timer will pause if you are attacking other players. That also applies to the 5 min counter when in Man hunt mode.

Losing Dark Zone ranking can mean a dark zone level downgrade!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my browsers language setting is automatically capitalising some words  ...

Comment: It seems like sometimes the enemies reset after you die and sometimes they don't. I died four times on a stronghold encounter my character was not suited for, and no new enemies spawned until the third death.

Comment: Dying as rouge you'll loose 4-5 times more credits and XP. You'll also not be able to respawn instantly, you have to wait 30s IIRC.

Comment: Per patch 1.0.2 penalities for dying in DZ will be significantly lower (both for rouge and not)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: > Non Rogue: You will lose all unsaved Dark Zone loot items

This isn't quite correct, whilst you will `drop` all unsaved loot items. There are public and private items, you can return to your corpse and recollect private items as these can't be stolen.

Comment: When is a item handled as private? Even teammates pick up the dropped gear accidently, when i dont tell them fast enough. Is there kind of mark?

Comment: The numbers you put  in Dark Zone credits and XP for dieing as Non-roque actually change with the character's level

Answer (score 2):

Regarding DZ amounts, these appear to be a function of your current DZ rank.

For example, I died at dz rank 14 and lost ~400 dz xp. But then died again at 20 dz rank and lost ~700 dz xp. I've put ~ because the amount seemed to vary depending on how far I was through that particular dz rank.

I believe the exact numbers are about 2% of your total rank for non rogue in PvP and then the rogue level increases that.
This table seems accurate compared to what I've seen:

https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/4afdng/full_dark_zone_xp_table_and_what_you_exactly_risk/

Comment: The mentioned reddit was posted before the patch 1.02. So the numbers got decreased.

Comment: Ah ok, I've not seen a better post though, they seem to match more or less with what I'm seeing in the DZ atm